# Canon MP980 Printer hard/complete reset

Tags: printer, reset

Is there any way to completely reset my MP980 Canon Printer, kind of like those little reset buttons in a hole you have to get a paperclip/pen to press?

The reason is after changing the network wireless security settings (and then changing them back to the original) the printer does not appear in network (My Network Places in XP) as it used to before I changed the settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From Canon Support Website](http://www.usa.canon.com/consumer/controller?act=ModelInfoAct&tabact=SupportDetailTabAct&fcategoryid=238&modelid=17357) (Direct link does not work, type reset and look at top option).

## Solution:  Setting the MP980 back to default settings

Instructions to change the machine back to its default settings.

1- Press the `<HOME>` button.

2- Use the Easy-Scroll Wheel or the right / left arrow to select [Settings], then press the `<OK>` button.

3- Use the Easy-Scroll Wheel or the right / left arrow to select [Device settings], then press the `<OK>` button.

[image]

4- Use the Easy-Scroll Wheel or the up / down arrow to select [Reset settings], then press the `<OK>` button.

[image]

5- Use the Easy-Scroll wheel or the up / down arrow to select [Yes] on the confirmation screen and then press `<OK>`.

6- Press the `<HOME>` button to return to the HOME menu.

Note: Changes the settings back to the default (factory settings), except for the language for LCD messages and the position of the print head.

Comment: I think this is the good answer. Do you think he will give you the bounty? ;-)

Comment: @r0ca I doubt it, but I am just happy to help!... If I get +4, I should get half automatically, but not expecting it!

Comment: Here's +1 from me. Canon's website just gives me a headache trying to find anything remotely useful.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt resetting the printer to factory default is the solution for the real problem: the changed network settings.

Care to elaborate on what exactly you have changed?

Did you run the network printer installation wizard, provided on the manufacturer's disk?